# Grid not getting populated in IE8

Tags: java, javascript

I am using jqxgrid for my application.The grid is working fine in chrome browser however in Internet Explorer 8 it is not.In IE8, the grid is getting populated in some pages while in some pages it is showing error “Object does not support this property or method-jqxrid.js”.However,it is supporting the same js file for other pages in IE8 only.I am using the same code for all the pages as well in same sequence order (for js imports).
Also, I have observed that,this problem is coming in pages in which I havent used iframe while grid is coming fine in pages in which grid is used in iframe.Can anybody please suggest what might be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Please check all syntax because “Object does not support this property or method-jqxrid.js” points you out that `jqxrid.js` is invalid syntax.

The file’s name is `jqxgrid.js` and there’s validation for invalid API so you can use the API as it is documented on this page: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-api.htm.